# Triage: question seems to not have enough information, but users have been answering. What to do?

Tags: support, triage, new-users

I have been seeing a lot of questions in the triage queue where the author:

1. Posts a long source code instead of a minimal working example;
2. Includes/does not include an error message;
3. Is not clear about what is the observed behavior; only what they expected.

From item #1 alone, I would mostly expect the question to be closed as "off-topic/why isn't this code working". However, people are answering and possibly understanding what the issue with the code is.

Here's the most recent case: [php simple swich case calculator function is not displaying results](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14763225).

On the one hand, I feel like this should be closed because it doesn't have a minimal working example and, while "it won't display the results" seems to reasonably explain the author's intended behavior, it is not clear on what the observed behavior is.

On the other hand, comments have been made with proposed solutions, which makes me feel inclined to give this a "Requires Editing". That is, if people understand the question well enough to answer, they could probably edit and improve it.

On the other other hand, I can't be certain that the proposed solution is conclusive to the author's issue. It could be the case that, yes, the comment in question does identify an issue wih the code, but this is not what is causing the error.

So what should I do here? Right now I'm skipping those, but skipping too much doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: If you were to post an extremely poor question in batchfile like *I set a variable and it doesn't take* we can guess the cause - we've seen it a lot and seen it expressed many ways (delayed expansion is needed). Yet if you are from unix the question is incomprehensible, if you don't answer questions in this field the question is still incomprehensible because it requires seeing lots of poor questions about this topic. If you are not an expert defer to those who claim to be.

Comment: If people are answering that suggests that it can't be VLQ, because at least some people can interpret it in a manner that allows it to be solved.  Whether the solution they provide is correct or not, at least some users feel that it's potentially answerable in its current form.  Apart from that... Never give up, trust your instincts!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do what **you** deem to be correct.

If **you** can't work it out then vote as "unsalvageable". If **you** think you know what the author intends then vote as "requires editing". You're not expected to be right 100% of the time, just use your best judgement and most of the time you'll pick the right option.

By all means look at what other's have commented, but at the end of the day it's your vote to use as you see fit.

Oh, and there's nothing wrong with hitting the "skip" button if you're really not sure. I wish more people would use it - not just in the triage queue but in all queues.

Comment: +1 for the attention to *skip*. Do not feel the urge to always act on a question or answer.